# Python: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python, file

I need to write a python script for summing decimal numbers in a text file (one line, one number). I wrote this script:

```
s = float()
f = open('/home/ale/file_numbers', 'r').readlines()
N = len(f)-1
for i in range(0,N):
    s += float(f)
```

but the problem is at the instruction   `s += float(f)`   infact the error returned is:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I cannot figure out how to solve such problem
Any suggestion?

Comment: To add to what others have already answered, there's another (logical) error in your code: `range(a,b)` returns numbers from a up to *but not including* b. So `N = len(f)-1` should really be `N=len(f)` Not to say that you should be traversing a list that way.

Answer (score 3):

This returns list of lines (as the name suggests):

```
open(...).readlines()
```

But you can iterate through lines directly:

```
s = float()
f = open('/home/ale/file_numbers', 'r')
for line in f:
    s += float(line)
```

And, just in case, if you do not `.close()` your file after opening, you can use this code:

```
s = float()
with open('/home/ale/file_numbers') as f:
    for line in f:
        s += float(line)
```

This is because:

- `with` statement handles closing the file after you go out of the nested block automatically,
- you can simply iterate through opened file, getting one line (ended with newline symbol) in each iteration,
- default `mode` for `open()` is "`r`", so you can omit it,

Comment: no need of stripping `\n` , `float()` takes care of that.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Okay, missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what is returned by `readlines`. It isn't a string, it's a list of strings.

You need to select a single string from the file somehow, or iterate through all of the lines.

```
s += float(f[0])
```